# Using python email or another module to send bokeh plot in email

Tags: javascript, python, html, email, bokeh

I have a complete html file that contains Bokeh plots. Now I am trying to send that html using python email module. I am simply using the third example given here: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/email-examples.html (how to create an HTML message....)

But this seems to simply send me a blank email message.

I also tried with some other html containing embedded javascript. That seems to come across just fine(with JS disabled, which I don't care about).

Any clues on what could be happening and what could I change ?

Here is the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bokeh Scatter Plots</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.0.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Bokeh.$(function() {
        var all_models = [{"attributes": {"line_color": {"value": "white"}, "fill_color": {"value": "#5ab738"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "fill_alpha": {"value": 0.7}, "height": {"units": "data", "field": "z"}, "width": {"units": "data", "field": "width_cat"}, "y": {"field": "midz"}, "x": {"field": "catz"}, "id": "20b3f29b-629c-4d0d-a8ef-9bc05e5b178a"}, "type": "Rect", "id": "20b3f29b-629c-4d0d-a8ef-9bc05e5b178a"}, {"attributes": {"nonselection_glyph": null, "data_source": {"type": "ColumnDataSource", "id": "23913a89-b55a-4191-a5c3-3195acc7e1f4"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "selection_glyph": null, "id": "5eda121f-edca-48cf-aed6-1e109b54b2ff", "glyph": {"type": "Rect", "id": "20b3f29b-629c-4d0d-a8ef-9bc05e5b178a"}}, "type": "GlyphRenderer", "id": "5eda121f-edca-48cf-aed6-1e109b54b2ff"}, {"attributes": {"geometries": [], "tags": [], "doc": null, "id": "c43afbcc-a846-4f33-a482-039a0fd206e8"}, "type": "ToolEvents", "id": "c43afbcc-a846-4f33-a482-039a0fd206e8"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Chart", "type": "Plot", "id": "36f2771e-837b-4b64-b541-523ef126784b"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "major_label_orientation": 0.7853981633974483, "axis_label": "categories", "formatter": {"type": "CategoricalTickFormatter", "id": "f27df891-c727-4511-af15-049332957dda"}, "ticker": {"type": "CategoricalTicker", "id": "9d14f049-833c-4895-bb18-a13fd30163a3"}, "id": "50005101-7498-4430-8b3e-fece52250277"}, "type": "CategoricalAxis", "id": "50005101-7498-4430-8b3e-fece52250277"}, {"subtype": "Chart", "type": "Plot", "id": "36f2771e-837b-4b64-b541-523ef126784b", "attributes": {"x_range": {"type": "FactorRange", "id": "46a7ffcd-19f4-4d8a-ae50-e01aa946b82e"}, "right": [], "above": [], "tags": [], "tools": [{"type": "PanTool", "id": "d6948ffa-b6f5-4379-a967-82dca90488a0"}, {"type": "WheelZoomTool", "id": "03df0ff2-3de4-4341-aecc-1bc593ebb8f2"}, {"type": "BoxZoomTool", "id": "3b6ab084-b09a-4131-809e-282113f78357"}, {"type": "PreviewSaveTool", "id": "8264e0e1-e9b3-44cd-aed7-02d01251240a"}, {"type": "ResizeTool", "id": "d3c48641-01cb-467c-91ee-3a0c6085d201"}, {"type": "ResetTool", "id": "3f0c4f54-5e2b-4253-b7e4-9bb9a7deabab"}, {"type": "HelpTool", "id": "3a1fb46c-8124-4374-83a4-2dd5bf4f6860"}], "title": "Bar example p", "renderers": [{"type": "CategoricalAxis", "id": "50005101-7498-4430-8b3e-fece52250277"}, {"type": "LinearAxis", "id": "42be7469-495b-4e8a-8021-a9a3191cecf0"}, {"type": "Grid", "id": "42bb2980-8afe-426d-9894-767dd3e4caad"}, {"type": "GlyphRenderer", "id": "8eb8810b-0e44-4851-89df-79debf7dbe2a"}, {"type": "GlyphRenderer", "id": "5eda121f-edca-48cf-aed6-1e109b54b2ff"}], "plot_width": 400, "extra_y_ranges": {}, "extra_x_ranges": {}, "tool_events": {"type": "ToolEvents", "id": "c43afbcc-a846-4f33-a482-039a0fd206e8"}, "plot_height": 400, "doc": null, "id": "36f2771e-837b-4b64-b541-523ef126784b", "y_range": {"type": "Range1d", "id": "90174572-530c-4de3-8906-e80952108b06"}, "below": [{"type": "CategoricalAxis", "id": "50005101-7498-4430-8b3e-fece52250277"}], "left": [{"type": "LinearAxis", "id": "42be7469-495b-4e8a-8021-a9a3191cecf0"}]}}, {"attributes": {"doc": null, "id": "9d14f049-833c-4895-bb18-a13fd30163a3", "tags": []}, "type": "CategoricalTicker", "id": "9d14f049-833c-4895-bb18-a13fd30163a3"}, {"attributes": {"doc": null, "id": "f27df891-c727-4511-af15-049332957dda", "tags": []}, "type": "CategoricalTickFormatter", "id": "f27df891-c727-4511-af15-049332957dda"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Chart", "type": "Plot", "id": "36f2771e-837b-4b64-b541-523ef126784b"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "axis_label": "values", "formatter": {"type": "BasicTickFormatter", "id": "a5efb989-af95-4129-983a-b867fe96eddf"}, "ticker": {"type": "BasicTicker", "id": "57a0ff59-725c-4d01-920a-2a3f8c65e6c4"}, "id": "42be7469-495b-4e8a-8021-a9a3191cecf0"}, "type": "LinearAxis", "id": "42be7469-495b-4e8a-8021-a9a3191cecf0"}, {"attributes": {"tags": [], "doc": null, "mantissas": [2, 5, 10], "id": "57a0ff59-725c-4d01-920a-2a3f8c65e6c4"}, "type": "BasicTicker", "id": "57a0ff59-725c-4d01-920a-2a3f8c65e6c4"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Chart", "type": "Plot", "id": "36f2771e-837b-4b64-b541-523ef126784b"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "dimension": 1, "ticker": {"type": "BasicTicker", "id": "57a0ff59-725c-4d01-920a-2a3f8c65e6c4"}, "id": "42bb2980-8afe-426d-9894-767dd3e4caad"}, "type": "Grid", "id": "42bb2980-8afe-426d-9894-767dd3e4caad"}, {"attributes": {"doc": null, "id": "a5efb989-af95-4129-983a-b867fe96eddf", "tags": []}, "type": "BasicTickFormatter", "id": "a5efb989-af95-4129-983a-b867fe96eddf"}, {"attributes": {"column_names": ["width_cat", "stackedz", "stackedy", "cat", "width", "zero", "midz", "midy", "y", "caty", "catz", "z"], "tags": [], "doc": null, "selected": {"2d": {"indices": []}, "1d": {"indices": []}, "0d": {"indices": [], "flag": false}}, "callback": null, "data": {"width_cat": [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2], "stackedz": [6.5, 9.5, 8.0, 6.0, 6.0], "stackedy": [3.0, 3.5, 1.0, 2.0, 2.5], "cat": ["C1", "C2", "C3", "D1", "D2"], "width": [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8], "zero": [7.0, 12.0, 14.0, 8.0, 7.0], "midz": [0.5, 2.5, 6.0, 2.0, 1.0], "midy": [3.0, 3.5, 1.0, 2.0, 2.5], "y": [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], "caty": ["C1:0.333333333333", "C2:0.333333333333", "C3:0.333333333333", "D1:0.333333333333", "D2:0.333333333333"], "catz": ["C1:0.666666666667", "C2:0.666666666667", "C3:0.666666666667", "D1:0.666666666667", "D2:0.666666666667"], "z": [1, 5, 12, 4, 2]}, "id": "23913a89-b55a-4191-a5c3-3195acc7e1f4"}, "type": "ColumnDataSource", "id": "23913a89-b55a-4191-a5c3-3195acc7e1f4"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Chart", "type": "Plot", "id": "36f2771e-837b-4b64-b541-523ef126784b"}, "dimensions": ["width", "height"], "tags": [], "doc": null, "id": "d6948ffa-b6f5-4379-a967-82dca90488a0"}, "type": "PanTool", "id": "d6948ffa-b6f5-4379-a967-82dca90488a0"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Chart", "type": "Plot", "id": "36f2771e-837b-4b64-b541-523ef126784b"}, "dimensions": ["width", "height"], "tags": [], "doc": null, "id": "03df0ff2-3de4-4341-aecc-1bc593ebb8f2"}, "type": "WheelZoomTool", "id": "03df0ff2-3de4-4341-aecc-1bc593ebb8f2"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Chart", "type": "Plot", "id": "36f2771e-837b-4b64-b541-523ef126784b"}, "dimensions": ["width", "height"], "tags": [], "doc": null, "id": "3b6ab084-b09a-4131-809e-282113f78357"}, "type": "BoxZoomTool", "id": "3b6ab084-b09a-4131-809e-282113f78357"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Chart", "type": "Plot", "id": "36f2771e-837b-4b64-b541-523ef126784b"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "id": "8264e0e1-e9b3-44cd-aed7-02d01251240a"}, "type": "PreviewSaveTool", "id": "8264e0e1-e9b3-44cd-aed7-02d01251240a"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Chart", "type": "Plot", "id": "36f2771e-837b-4b64-b541-523ef126784b"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "id": "d3c48641-01cb-467c-91ee-3a0c6085d201"}, "type": "ResizeTool", "id": "d3c48641-01cb-467c-91ee-3a0c6085d201"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Chart", "type": "Plot", "id": "36f2771e-837b-4b64-b541-523ef126784b"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "id": "3f0c4f54-5e2b-4253-b7e4-9bb9a7deabab"}, "type": "ResetTool", "id": "3f0c4f54-5e2b-4253-b7e4-9bb9a7deabab"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Chart", "type": "Plot", "id": "36f2771e-837b-4b64-b541-523ef126784b"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "id": "3a1fb46c-8124-4374-83a4-2dd5bf4f6860"}, "type": "HelpTool", "id": "3a1fb46c-8124-4374-83a4-2dd5bf4f6860"}, {"attributes": {"callback": null, "factors": ["C1", "C2", "C3", "D1", "D2"], "doc": null, "tags": [], "id": "46a7ffcd-19f4-4d8a-ae50-e01aa946b82e"}, "type": "FactorRange", "id": "46a7ffcd-19f4-4d8a-ae50-e01aa946b82e"}, {"attributes": {"end": 13.200000000000001, "callback": null, "doc": null, "tags": [], "start": 0, "id": "90174572-530c-4de3-8906-e80952108b06"}, "type": "Range1d", "id": "90174572-530c-4de3-8906-e80952108b06"}, {"attributes": {"line_color": {"value": "white"}, "fill_color": {"value": "#f22c40"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "fill_alpha": {"value": 0.7}, "height": {"units": "data", "field": "y"}, "width": {"units": "data", "field": "width_cat"}, "y": {"field": "midy"}, "x": {"field": "caty"}, "id": "43271b33-7e9c-4120-a177-4d0f1c233de1"}, "type": "Rect", "id": "43271b33-7e9c-4120-a177-4d0f1c233de1"}, {"attributes": {"nonselection_glyph": null, "data_source": {"type": "ColumnDataSource", "id": "23913a89-b55a-4191-a5c3-3195acc7e1f4"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "selection_glyph": null, "id": "8eb8810b-0e44-4851-89df-79debf7dbe2a", "glyph": {"type": "Rect", "id": "43271b33-7e9c-4120-a177-4d0f1c233de1"}}, "type": "GlyphRenderer", "id": "8eb8810b-0e44-4851-89df-79debf7dbe2a"}];
        Bokeh.load_models(all_models);
        var plots = [{'modeltype': 'Plot', 'elementid': '#806c01c5-0a0d-4d12-9df9-5de64399e878', 'modelid': '36f2771e-837b-4b64-b541-523ef126784b'}];
        for (idx in plots) {
            var plot = plots[idx];
            var model = Bokeh.Collections(plot.modeltype).get(plot.modelid);
            Bokeh.logger.info('Realizing plot:')
            Bokeh.logger.info(' - modeltype: ' + plot.modeltype);
            Bokeh.logger.info(' - modelid: ' + plot.modelid);
            Bokeh.logger.info(' - elementid: ' + plot.elementid);
            var view = new model.default_view({
                model: model,
                el: plot.elementid
            });
            Bokeh.index[plot.modelid] = view;
        }
    });
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="plotdiv" id="806c01c5-0a0d-4d12-9df9-5de64399e878"></div>    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

me = 'abc@mac.com'
you = 'abc@abc.com'

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Link JavaScript big"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
#text = "Hi!\nHow are you?\nHere is the link you wanted:\nhttps://www.python.org"

# example below
'''
html = """\ 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
"""
'''

# html goes here
html = """\

"""


# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
#part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
#msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via local SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
# sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
# and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

The bokeh html goes in the triple quotes (just like the example above it) beneath the comment "# html goes here"

Comment: Oh I know whats happening. Javascript is getting disabled. JS does the rendering and so nothing gets rendered (since Js is getting disabled). Thanks.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: @PascalvKooten Haven't solved it yet Pascal. I am going to try using PhantomJS to render webpage to image file. If you have any ideas please do let me know.

Comment: If you just need static images, you can currently get PNGs with the "save" tool (requires UI interaction). We are working on headless generation of images, I'm not sure whether many clients will execute JS code in embedded HTML, if not Bokeh will not render.

Comment: @bigreddot Well I need to do this in a programmatic fashion. You know how matplotlib allows you to save files in various formats.

Comment: Yes it does, but it is also not rendering on a different platform in a different language. It's actually a surprisingly difficult technical proposition to add static image support to Bokeh. There are several potential avenues, and all of them have serious drawbacks. It has been an open issue for some time now, but we do hope to have something later this year. In the mean time, for static plots I have to recommend MPL.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, emails don't render HTML.

There are three options that come to my mind: turn the plot into an image and send that, put the plot to a server and put a link to the plot to the email or send the HTML as an attachment. I think you probably cannot display the plot as-is on the HTML body alone.

One easy way is to put the plot as an attachment is to do it via Red Mail:

```
from redmail import EmailSender

email = EmailSender(
    host="smtp.myserver.com", port=587,
    username="me@example.com", password="<PASSWORD>"
)

plot_content = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">....</html>"

msg = email.send(
    sender=["me@example.com"],
    receivers=["you@example.com"],
    subject="Link JavaScript big",
    text="The plot is attached.",
    attachments={'plot.html': plot_content}, 
)
```

It also supports embedded images to the HTML body if you prefer that route. It is also highly customizable and quite feature-rich thus most likely enough for your use case.

Red Mail's documentation: https://red-mail.readthedocs.io

Disclaimer: I'm the author, use it as you see fit.